# Put text and numbers in boxes

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, fastreport

Using `FastReport` , how can I put `Text` and `Numbers` from database in boxes like :

```
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

So "Sami" it becomes :

[image]

and the same for numbers too, I try to do it with `TfrxLineView` but I fail.

Comment: You can [create a custom control](https://www.fast-report.com/documentation/DevMan/index.html?custom_report_components_writing.htm) for that. Or build it dynamically from existing controls (separately for each char or number).

Comment: @Victoria What if I don't know how to create it? Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I guess so. You could take e.g. text object, resize it, write a single letter, center the text, setup its `Frame` and exclude `ftTop` flag from the `Frame.Typ` property. That should result in a single box that you want. And if you create such boxes at runtime by iterating all the chars in a string placing them at horizontal position shifted by the iterator, you are done.

Comment: @Victoria Yeah , it's a good idea thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the easy way :

- Drop 4 `TfrxMemoView` component in your report (or as you need) like :

[image]

- In `OnPreview` event of your report, set your code for example:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.frxReport1Preview(Sender: TObject);
  var Str : WideString;   I : Integer;  Mem : TfrxMemoView;
  begin
     Str := 'Sami';   // Or get it from query/table (database)

     // Find the TFrxMemoView Component and set in it the String you want
     for I := 1 to 4 do
       begin
         Mem := frxReport1.FindObject('M'+IntToStr(I)) as TfrxMemoView;
         Mem.Text := Str[I];
       end;
    end;
  ```
- The result will be :

[image]

Update :

You can also do it programmatically as :

```
var RT : TfrxBand;
    Mem : array [1..100] of TfrxMemoView ;
    i : Byte;
    Name : WideString;
begin
  // Find the band
  RT := frxReport1.FindObject('RT') as TfrxBand;
  // Set the String
  Name := 'DELPHI FAST REPORT';
  for I := 1 to Length(Name) do
    begin
      Mem[i] := TfrxMemoView.Create(RT);
      Mem[i].Text :=  Name[i];
      Mem[i].Font.Style := [fsBold];
      Mem[i].Frame.Width := 2;
      Mem[i].Height := 20;
      Mem[i].AutoWidth := False;
      Mem[i].HAlign := haCenter;
      Mem[i].Frame.Typ := [ftLeft , ftBottom , ftRight];
      Mem[i].Width := 20;
      if i =1 then
        Mem[i].Left := 0
          else
            Mem[i].Left := Mem[i-1].Left + 5 + 15;
    end;
  frxReport1.ShowReport();
end;
```

The result is :

[image]

Comment: You can even create them at runtime if you want to have your code more flexible. From Delphi, or FR code you can create report visual objects. The only a bit _difficult_ concern is how to position them on the report.

Comment: @Victoria Yes , I know , that's why I choose this solution (at least for now) because I try to create them at runtime and face a problem in the position.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ready made control for displaying characters in boxes as you ask for. Therefore you need to paint this yourself on the canvas you choose.

Here's an example of how to do it in a `TPaintBox`, `pbText` is here a string field of the demo form, and holds the text to be displayed in the paint box:

```
procedure TForm17.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);var
  i, n, x, y: integer;
  siz: TSize;
  pb: TPaintBox;
begin
  n := 10;  // character cells
  pb := Sender as TPaintBox;
  siz := pb.Canvas.TextExtent('Wp');

  // draw character cells
  x := 4; y := siz.cy+2;
  for i := 0 to n do
  begin
    pb.Canvas.MoveTo(i * siz.cx + x, 0);
    pb.Canvas.LineTo(i * siz.cx + x, y);
  end;
  pb.Canvas.MoveTo(x, y);
  pb.Canvas.LineTo(n * siz.cx + 4, y);

  // draw characters horizontally in center of box
  for i := 1 to Length(pbText) do
  begin
    x := (4 + (i-1)*siz.cx + (siz.cx - pb.Canvas.TextWidth(pbText[i])) div 2);
    y := 0;
    pb.Canvas.TextOut(x, y, UpperCase(pbText[i])); // force upcase
//    pb.Canvas.TextOut(x, y, pbText[i]);            // or don't
  end;
end;
```

And to use it

```
procedure TForm17.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  pbText := 'Sami Wiim';
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: In reports, also scaling factors might be considered. But it depends on final needs. Well done!

Comment: Hey Tom, btw what `WIIM` mean? :)

Comment: @Sami Not sure anymore, but probably I just tested how various characters are centered horizontally, for me those characters do not mean anything. Did it take you 3 months before you noticed that I answered your question? :)

Comment: @TomBrunberg No, just did not focus on the word "WIIM", I was a bit busy, but soon remembered to ask you about the meaning :). Thanks for the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and and a little ugly method to do this.

1. In Fast Report:

-place a Text object like this : **[TEST_STR]**;

-set text style to **Underline**;

2.In Delphi

-make function to convert a string to formated string. 
For example :

input: `SAMI`

output:  `| S | A | M | I |`

-in OnGetValue event of FastReport call this function:

```
procedure TMainForm.frxReport1GetValue(const VarName: string;
  var Value: Variant);
begin
  if VarName = 'TEST_STR' then Value :=  MyFunctionToFormatStr('SAMI');

end;
```

That's all.

The result look like :

[image]